# http authentication with android

Tags: android, json, http, authentication

I have a problem with a http authentication.
No problem to connect with other web-service without authentication.
But I don't know how i can connect to this http authentication with android.
So in my app, i have two textfield (login and password). And a button to connect to an address and get informations about the user (json data).
In a first time, i would like to pass identifiers in adress : https://proxyepn-test.epnbn.net/wsapi/user. Like https://login:password@proxyepn-test.epnbn.net/wsapi/user. And display data ine the log.
Can you help me ?

` 
I try this.

```
public HashMap<String, String> btn_connexion(View view) {
    etPseudo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    etMdp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final String pseudo = etPseudo.getText().toString();
    final String mdp = etMdp.getText().toString();


    //String urldisplay = "https://" + pseudo + ":" + mdp + "@proxyepn-test.epnbn.net/wsapi/user";

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureErro {
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        String creds = String.format("%s:%s", pseudo, mdp);
        String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(creds.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        params.put("Authorization", auth);
        return params;


    }



}`
```

//class to establish the connection

```
public static class RestOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String content;
    String error;
    String data = "";


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        BufferedReader br = null;

        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);

            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStreamWr.write(data);
            outputStreamWr.flush();

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while((line = br.readLine())!=null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }

            content = sb.toString();
            Log.i("content",content);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            error = e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            error = e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if(br != null) {
                    br.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return content;
    }

}
```

//an example of connection with a web-service without authentication

```
String restURL = "https://proxyepn-test.epnbn.net/wsapi/epn";
    RestOperation test = new RestOperation();
    String[]tabInfos = null;
    try {

        String test2 = test.execute(restURL).get().toString();
        Log.i("result",test2);

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(test2);
        JSONObject data = obj.getJSONObject("data");
        Iterator<String> iterator = data.keys();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            String key = iterator.next();
            String name = data.getString(key);

            tabInfos = name.split(",");


            ...



            }
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Encode your username and password to base64 string and pass to header of your request in `Authorization` key.

You can use [volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) library and pass username and password in header as:

```
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            String creds = String.format("%s:%s", "your-username", "your-password");
            String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(creds.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
            params.put("Authorization", auth);
            return params;
        }
```

If you are using `HttpUrlConnection` then pass basic auth in header as:

```
        String creds = String.format("%s:%s", "your-username", "your-password");
        String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(creds.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        yourHttpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", auth);
```

Comment: thx but i don't know how to use this. I edit my question to be more precise.

Comment: @GregConstantin i have edited the answer add those lines in your RestOperation class doInBackground  method

Comment: @GregConstantin have you put String creds = String.format("%s:%s", "your-username", "your-password");
        String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(creds.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        yourHttpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", auth); lines in your RestOperation Class below yout HttpUrlConnection??